# What is the most secure database?

Tags: sql-injection, databases, vulnerability, server, denial-of-service

I need to learn about database systems, but first I need to know which is the safest. For example, information like government data need to be protected, so what is the best database to handle this kind of information, I know that there are no complete database systems that are fully protected, but at least I need a system that can't lose information.

And I have another question, what's your thought about Microsoft SQL Server from a security perspective, and how many vulnerabilities does it have compared to other database systems?

Comment: related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/out-of-the-box-database-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security of a database system, or any system for that matter, is about more than simply which type you use. Who has access, is remote access possible, can root login remotely, is there a web interface, and if so, is it secure against injection attacks?

There's hundreds of factors. You could try asking a more specific question.

Comment: Some databases have more user and access management, say SQL Server vs Cassandra.